# onLocationChanged not working when re-enable gps (android)

Tags: android, gps

`requestLocationUpdates` in onCreate, and the gps is disable. `onProviderEnabled` is called and log shows gps provider is disable.

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

I got `Location` from `onLocationChanged`, it shows that the provider is network provider. Now enable gps and disable gps. then `onLocationChanged` not called anymore.

here's my listener:

```
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle arg2) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider + ".." + status);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        updateCurrentLocation(location);
    }
};
```

update:

If I just `requestLocationUpdates` with `NETWORK_PROVIDER`, onLocationChanged works fine.

how do I get the location correctly? Help!

android: 8.0

Comment: Try to to remove network provider to see how gps works. I think it will take some time before onLocationChanged to be invoked.